# Call php using arguments from a text box

Tags: php, html

I want to make a website that has a text box and if an user enters "hello" and clicks submit I want to show example.com/test.php?link=hello
How can I do that? The php is already written I just need to make something with html or php to be able to show example.com/test.php?link=whatUserEnters

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form should have the method "get" defined. Then on the test.php page you just

```
<form method="get" action="test.php">
...
    <input type="text" name="link"/>
</form>
```

and on the test.php

```
<? echo $_GET['link']; ?>
```

or

```
<?= $_GET['link']?>
```

Edit with the POST solution:

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
...
    <input type="text" name="link"/>
</form>
```

and on the test.php

```
<? echo $_POST['link']; ?>
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much

Comment: Can I somehow hide the URL that is being called?

Comment: Click on the flag if it's solved please :]
Yeah you can replace the "get" by "post" in the form and the PHP replace $_GET by $_POST

Comment: Right now im using <form action="http://hiddenurl.com/test.php" class="form-box d-flex justify-content-between">
<input type="text" placeholder="Link" class="form-control" name="link">
<button type="submit" class="btn search-btn">Get It</button>
</form> But I get a HTTPS error because of mixed content is there a way to solve that message? The php is not in HTTPS and my website is in https. I want my website in full https

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <!--just create a text box, give an id to it.-->
    <input type="text" id="text_to_display" />

    <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="concat();" />

    <!--Create a label or div assign a separate id to it too.-->
    <p id="concatenated_text"></p>

    <script>
        //Create a function in javascript.
        function concat() {
            //Get the value in function using that id.
            var text = document.getElementById("text_to_display").value;

            //Concatenate the value with the string and put it in div using id.
            var final_text = "example.com/test.php?link="+text;
            // you can use location.href to use it for link purpose
            location.href = final_text;
        }

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```